# How to select file from internal & external storage in andorid

Tags: android, storage

Hi I am trying to create an file selector to select file from device and then upload it to the server.So i tried few example for same but every time i stuck at it only shows internal storage drive of the device not the external storage.
I tried the example from here [File Explorer Example](http://custom-android-dn.blogspot.in/2013/01/create-simple-file-explore-in-android.html)

but same i only shows Internal sdcard. when

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    currentDir = new File("/sdcard/");
    fill(currentDir); 
}
```

and If i change to mnt then show the option external storage after pressing the back button..

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    currentDir = new File("/mnt/");
    fill(currentDir); 
}
```

what i want is when click on the browse button it should show only two option's one internal storage and second external storage as per the device config. i.e if it has these drives.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: refer http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Comment: Every device has internal and external storage. If a micro SD card is present we call that removable storage. So there can be three kinds of storage. Mostly you cannot find easy the path to removable media. Please do not make yet another file manager that limits what the user can see from the file system. (I hate them). Just start at /mnt or /storage and allow all up to /.

Comment: /storage/ worked know it shows both internal as well as erternal storage device. thanks @greenapps

Comment: Not on every device! And again you missed removable storage. Micro SD card and usb storage.

Answer (score 0):

For external storage.

```
String path = null;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 8) {
        path = root.getAbsolutePath() + "/Android/data/com.packagename/files/";
    } else {
        File file = getExternalFilesDir(null);//getAbsolutePath();
        if (file == null) {
            path = root.getAbsolutePath() + "/Android/data/com.packagename/files/";
        } else {
            path = file.getAbsolutePath();
        }
    }
```

For Internal storage you can use

```
FileInputStream stream = context.openFileInput("sp_key_file");
```